# Android Animations?

Tags: android, mobile, opengl-es

I would like to create an android game but one thing I do not understand is what I should use to create the graphics for it,

It is going to be a 2d game with movable images but would I use **OpenGL ES** or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You should use OpenGl ES to get the best performance. Alternatively you could use Canvas drawing which is the default way of drawing in Android...

But the easiest way of creating an Android game probably by using  [Unity 3D](http://unity3d.com/)...
Not Java development thoe :)

Answer (score 0):

Try it via [libgdx](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/)

it is easy to use.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[LibGDX](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/) is a fast library that is essentially a wrapper around OpenGL, saving you a lot of time. Unfortunately the documentation around it is severely lacking, so there is quite a steep learning curve, but once you are used to the library development is very fast.

It also gives you the option to run your code as a java application instead of the android emulator, which saves a lot of time.

There are a few good tutorials on the wiki to help you get started, but you will ultimately have to rely on the Java Docs and the test code to see how to use the library properly.

There are other options such as [AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/), which is easier to learn but has less flexbility and runs slower, so ultimately you are better off with LibGDX.